# How can I pay with Bitcoin on overstock.com o.co?

Tags: payment, retail

I just registered at overstock.com to buy something, because I heard that they accept bitcoins as of today. But when I checked out, there was no option to pay with bitcoins. Only PayPal and credit cards.

Do I have to do something specific to activate bitcoin payment?

Can someone post a screenshot of a working Bitcoin checkout?

Comment: Googling turns up some suggestions that it may be US-only for now.  Where are you located?

Comment: I’m located in Europe. :-( I thought that was the advantage of Bitcoin and overstock: Paying from all over the world. Disappointing.

Comment: According to [someone on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1utcz6/bitcoin_payments_are_now_live_on_overstockcom/) international is coming soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for the USA at the moment according to [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1utcz6/bitcoin_payments_are_now_live_on_overstockcom/)

> If you go to the checkout page on Overstock you'll see an option to
>   pay with Bitcoin!
>
> -edit- For now it's only available on the U.S. checkout but I hear from reliable sources that they will roll it out to international
>   after a bake in period.